# Some Minecraft sound effects on Mac are too quiet

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I bought Minecraft last year and all went well until I bought a Mac. Now, the following sounds are either missing or **very** quiet:

- Walking on any material.
- Breaking materials.
- Placing materials.

Pistons, doors and mob sounds are fine.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Turn your sound up?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to clear your `[home]/Library/Application Support/minecraft/sounds` folder.

It will then ingame download the sounds, i have read somewhere long while ago that you actually need to be in a world to do that. Don't know what happened about this bug.

You could aswell search for a ZIP of the .minecraft/sounds folder online.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in the Terminal:

```
cd ~/library/"application support"
rm -r minecraft
```

then download it again and install it.

Comment: Done that countless times. No difference.

Comment: @user1453094 It's a little known fact that the Minecraft.app that you download is *not* the game, it's just the installer/launcher, so redownloading it will never fix problems. To reinstall you have to do a forced download (in launchers Options), or remove the game files from their hidden install location and let the launcher reinstall them, as Jeffrey shows in the edited answer.

Comment: @Jeffrey Deleting and redownloading `Minecraft.app` doesn't do anything, so you should remove that advice from the answer.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, ok.